# AWS Elastic Beanstalk ebextension not executing shell script to use npm install

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ebextensions

I need to install a separate framework that I created inside my node js application running on elastic beanstalk.

I have tried putting scripts inside my main package.json file but I get permission errors when it installs.

So I created a config file and tried running npm install from the container_commands. It didn't want to run npm as it said the command was missing. I tried adding the correct environment path variables to npm, which work when done manually through ssh, but it gave the same error that it couldn't find the npm command.

So finally.

I created a bash script through the ebextension which installs the application and I run that script from the container_commands.

The script gets created correctly but never runs. If I ssh into the instances and execute it manually as sudo it works.
The app deploys without erros but it never seems to execute the script, I know this because the node_modules folders are never created.

I'm not sure where to look for errors for this in my logs and when I tried I didn't find anything useful.

Here is my ebextension:

```
files:
    "/tmp/install_application.sh":
        mode: "000755"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
            #!/bin/bash
            export PATH=$PATH:`ls -td /opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-* | head -1`/bin
            eval "cd /var/app/current/library/server && npm install --production"
            eval "cd /var/app/current && npm install --production"

container_commands:
    00-install-application:
    command: "sh /tmp/install_application.sh"
```

Comment: Change the command to "su -c 'sh /tmp/install_application.sh' - root" and now try it will work

Comment: Thanks @error2007s, I tried it and it didn't seem to work from eb deploy. When I tried this via ssh it wanted me to insert a password. I guess thats why it wasn't working from eb deploy.

Anyway around this?

Comment: I also tried sudo su -c 'sh /tmp/install_application.sh' - root and it didnt work.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find the answer to this. 
I had a few issues with the script.

1. Old scripts were still in the hooks folders from previous attempts.
2. I was firing the script before the project had even unzipped yet or I was firing the script after the project had deployed.
3. I was installing the modules to the final destination /var/app/current which was being overwritten once the deployed app was installed.

Here is the final script.

```
files:
   "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/enact/00-install-application.sh":
   mode: "000755"
   owner: root
   group: root
   content: |
       #!/bin/bash
       PATH=$PATH:`ls -td /opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-* | head -1`/bin
       cd "/tmp/deployment/application/library/server"
       npm install --production
```